# Pass data from ListView in activity to fragment

Tags: java, android-studio

How to pass data from ListView in activity to fragment To view the location on the map, look on my method addMarker() in FragmentTwoClass?
.....................................................................................................

FavoritesActivity:

public class Favorites extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayList<MapModel> mMapList;  // ArrayList of MovieModel
private MapCustomAdapterFavorites mAdapter;  // CustomAdapter of MainActivity
private GetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites mGetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites;  // AsyncTask for AddMovie to add movie to MainActivity
private ListView mListView;  // ListView of MainActivity
private MapDBHelperFavorites mMapDBHelper;  // The SQLiteHelper of the app
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;  // SwipeRe freshLayout of MainActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("LocationProject");

    mListView = findViewById(R.id.listFavorites);  // ID of the ListView of MainActivity
    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);  // ID of the SwipeRefreshLayout of MainActivity

    mMapDBHelper = new MapDBHelperFavorites(this);  // Put the SQLiteHelper in MainActivity
    mMapList = mMapDBHelper.getAllMaps();  // Put the getAllMovies of SQLiteHelper in the ArrayList of MainActivity
    mAdapter = new MapCustomAdapterFavorites(this, mMapList);  // Comparing the ArrayList of MainActivity to the CustomAdapter
    registerForContextMenu(mListView);

    // Put AsyncTask in the ListView of MainActivity to execute the SQLiteHelper
    mGetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites = new GetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites(mListView);
    mGetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites.execute(mMapDBHelper);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FragmentTwo fragObj = new FragmentTwo();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(getString(R.string.map_edit_favorites), (mMapList.get(position)));
            fragObj.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    });

    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));  // Colors of the SwipeRefreshLayout of MainActivity
    // Refresh the MovieDBHelper of app in ListView of MainActivity
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mGetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites = new GetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites(mListView);
            mGetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites.execute(mMapDBHelper);

            // Vibration for 0.1 second
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else {
                vibrator.vibrate(100);
            }

            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());  // Refresh activity

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Favorites.this, "The list are refreshed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View view = toast.getView();
            view.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            TextView text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
            toast.show();  // Toast

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}


// Sets off the menu of activity_menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.favorites_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Sets off the menu of list_menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.favorites_list_menu, menu);
}

// Options in the activity_menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mute:  // Mute all the sound in app
            AudioManager managerYes = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            managerYes.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);

            Toast toastMute = Toast.makeText(this, "The sound are mute!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View viewMute = toastMute.getView();
            viewMute.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            TextView textMute = viewMute.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            textMute.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
            toastMute.show();  // Toast
            break;
        case R.id.unMute:  // Allow all the sound in app
            AudioManager managerNo = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            managerNo.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);

            Toast toastUnMute = Toast.makeText(this, "The sound are on!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View viewUnMute = toastUnMute.getView();
            viewUnMute.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            TextView textUnMute = viewUnMute.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            textUnMute.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
            toastUnMute.show();  // Toast
            break;
        case R.id.intentMainActivity:
            Intent intentBackMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentBackMainActivity);
            break;
        case R.id.deleteAllDataFavorites:  // Delete all data of the app for delete all the data of the app
            Intent intentDeleteAllData = new Intent(this, DeleteAllDataFavorites.class);
            startActivity(intentDeleteAllData);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Options in the list_menu
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int listPosition = info.position;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:  // Edit the movies on MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Favorites.this, EditMap.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.map_id), mMapList.get(listPosition).getId());
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.map_edit), mMapList.get(listPosition));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.shareIntent:
            String name = mMapList.get(listPosition).getName();
            String address = mMapList.get(listPosition).getVicinity();
            double lat = mMapList.get(listPosition).getLat();
            double lng = mMapList.get(listPosition).getLng();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nLatitude: " + lat + "\nLongitude: " + lng);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:  // Delete item(movie) on MainActivity
            mGetMapsAsyncTaskFavorites.deleteMovie(listPosition);
            mMapDBHelper.deleteMap(mMapList.get(listPosition));

            Intent intentDeleteData = new Intent(Favorites.this, DeleteMap.class);
            startActivity(intentDeleteData);
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

FragmentTwoClass:

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private MapView mMapView;
private View mView;
private MapModel mapModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_layout, container, false);
    mapModel = (MapModel) getArguments().getSerializable(getString(R.string.map_edit_favorites)); // GetSerializable for the texts
    return mView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    addMarker();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

public void addMarker() {
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mapModel.getLat(), mapModel.getLng())).title("Elior home");
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you are already passing data from listView to Fragment, what's the actual problem ? Are you not able to use mapModel in Fragment ?

Comment: @ sohaib karim  I can't use in the map, it's not open to me the fragment of the map, it's write to me my position and id(I think i didn't need id) are 0.